# Copy columns to dataframe using panda

Tags: pandas

I have two dataframes and I want to copy the values from one to another. Returned NaN when copying column values to dataframe

These are my df:

`data1 = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]`
`rc = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Sold', 'Leads'])`

`data2 = [['Company1','2017-05-01',0, 0], ['Company1','2017-05-01',0, 0], ['Company1','2017-05-01',0, 0]]`
`final = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns = ['company','date','2019_sold', '2019_leads'])`

I tried loc indexing

`final.loc[(final['date'] == '2017-05-01') & (final['company'] == 'Company1'),['2019_sold','2019_leads']] = rc[['Leads','Sold']]`

I expect them to copy the exact value of rc df to final df but the values returned `NaN`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `update`

```
rc.index=final.index[(final['date'] == '2017-05-01') & (final['company'] == 'Company1')]
rc.columns=['2019_sold','2019_leads']
final.update(rc)
final
Out[165]: 
    company        date  2019_sold  2019_leads
0  Company1  2017-05-01          1           2
1  Company1  2017-05-01          3           4
2  Company1  2017-05-01          5           6
```